# How to solve a Windows 10 Scheduler error

Tags: windows-10, taskscheduler

I have several tasks in Windows 10 that have recently failed.  I've made no recent changes to the server.  The tasks were working fine for years, and then started failing in December of 2017.  I have the Scheduler tasks configured to run on System Startup.
When I check the History tab, I see:

> Task Start Failed error: Additional Data: Error Value: 2147943712.

The task/General Tab is configured as follows:

- Run whether user is logged on or not
- Do not store password.
- Run with highest privileges
- Configure for Windows 10

The user account is "Admin".  That user has no password and is an administrator.

When I try to Run the task from the Selected Item / Run option, the scheduler logs the same error.  Based on other posts, I've tried to edit the User Account, re-typing Admin and pressing the Check Names button.  It shows the SERVERNAME\Admin, and does not prompt for a password.

How can I configure the task manager so that it does not produce this error?

Comment: Have you tried assigning a password to the acct...I'd suspect having an account with no password and trying to run jobs with it is the problem

Comment: This looks like a general computing question, not a programming question - it should be on superuser.com instead

Answer (score 2):

The error code returned (0x80070520 in hex) is "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."

According to this [technet blog entry](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/04/18/task-scheduler-error-a-specified-logon-session-does-not-exist/), the solution may be to disable the security policy which prevents local storage of passwords.

Comment: Hello Ferruccio,  Thanks for the response.  The SECPOL.MSC screens look slightly different because the PC is Windows 10, but I already had that policy set to disabled.  I don't want a password.  The PC is setup in a physically secure room and on a secure subnet.  This configuration worked well for years, but something with Windows changed a few months ago.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your error, try to take this measure. Hope this help.

To fix this up Change the following Registry key to value 0x0

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa 
Value Name: disabledomaincreds 
Value Type: REG_DWORD 
Values: 0 (allow domain credentials to be stored)
```

Comment: Hello Sandeep,  Thanks for responding.  I checked that setting in RegEdit and it was already set to zero.

Comment: helped me though, thanks for posting it.